# continue in callback action without view in yii

Tags: callback, action

I need to display a message to the user when he is referred to the callback page and then to finish, to wait a few seconds because of the time-consuming queries, because in this case the screen will turn white and the user will think that an error has occurred.  !  Because the callback action does not have a view, these changes must be applied in the action itself. I would be grateful if someone could help

continue in callback action yii